# Android Calculator App Crashing immediately when run

Tags: java, android, xml, calculator

I'm working on a calculator app for my class project in school, but there seem to be some errors behind the scenes that are not syntax-based. I try to run my app it crashes. I have been unable to find my error but it always crashes after I hit the submit button. I haven't had an app just completely refuse to run.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.stins.calculator">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.example.stins.calculator.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.stins.calculator;

import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.stins.calculator.Calculator;
import com.example.stins.calculator.CalculatorImpl;
import com.example.stins.calculator.Config;
import com.example.stins.calculator.Constants;
import com.example.stins.calculator.Formatter;
import com.example.stins.calculator.R;
import com.example.stins.calculator.Utils;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import butterknife.OnLongClick;
import me.grantland.widget.AutofitHelper;

public class MainActivity extends SimpleActivity implements Calculator {@BindView(R.id.result)
    TextView mResult;@BindView(R.id.formula)
    TextView mFormula;

    private static CalculatorImpl mCalc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        CalculatorImpl calc = new CalculatorImpl(this);
        AutofitHelper.create(mResult);
        AutofitHelper.create(mFormula);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_plus)
    public void plusClicked() {
        mCalc.handleOperation(Constants.PLUS);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_minus)
    public void minusClicked() {
        mCalc.handleOperation(Constants.MINUS);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_multiply)
    public void multiplyClicked() {
        mCalc.handleOperation(Constants.MULTIPLY);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_divide)
    public void divideClicked() {
        mCalc.handleOperation(Constants.DIVIDE);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_modulo)
    public void moduloClicked() {
        mCalc.handleOperation(Constants.MODULO);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_power)
    public void powerClicked() {
        mCalc.handleOperation(Constants.POWER);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_root)
    public void rootClicked() {
        mCalc.handleOperation(Constants.ROOT);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_clear)
    public void clearClicked() {
        mCalc.handleClear();
    }

    @OnLongClick(R.id.btn_clear)
    public boolean clearLongClicked() {
        mCalc.handleReset();
        return true;
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_equals)
    public void equalsClicked() {
        mCalc.handleEquals();
    }

    @OnClick({
        R.id.btn_decimal,
        R.id.btn_0,
        R.id.btn_1,
        R.id.btn_2,
        R.id.btn_3,
        R.id.btn_4,
        R.id.btn_5,
        R.id.btn_6,
        R.id.btn_7,
        R.id.btn_8,
        R.id.btn_9
    })
    public void numpadClick(View view) {
        numpadClicked(view.getId());
    }

    public void numpadClicked(int id) {
        mCalc.numpadClicked(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String value) {
        mResult.setText(value);
    }

    // used only by Robolectric
    @Override
    public void setValueDouble(double d) {
        mCalc.setValue(Formatter.doubleToString(d));
        mCalc.setLastKey(Constants.DIGIT);
    }

    public void setFormula(String value) {
        mFormula.setText(value);
    }

    public CalculatorImpl getCalc() {
        return mCalc;
    }
}
```

CalcImpl.java

```
package com.example.stins.calculator;

public class CalculatorImpl {
    private String mDisplayedValue;
    private String mDisplayedFormula;
    private String mLastKey;
    private String mLastOperation;
    private Calculator mCallback;

    private boolean mIsFirstOperation;
    private boolean mResetValue;
    private double mBaseValue;
    private double mSecondValue;

    public CalculatorImpl(Calculator calculator) {
        mCallback = calculator;
        resetValues();
        setValue("0");
        setFormula("");
    }

    public CalculatorImpl(Calculator calculatorInterface, String value) {
        mCallback = calculatorInterface;
        resetValues();
        mDisplayedValue = value;
        setFormula("");
    }

    private void resetValueIfNeeded() {
        if (mResetValue) mDisplayedValue = "0";

        mResetValue = false;
    }

    private void resetValues() {
        mBaseValue = 0;
        mSecondValue = 0;
        mResetValue = false;
        mLastKey = "";
        mLastOperation = "";
        mDisplayedValue = "";
        mDisplayedFormula = "";
        mIsFirstOperation = true;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        mCallback.setValue(value);
        mDisplayedValue = value;
    }

    private void setFormula(String value) {
        mCallback.setFormula(value);
        mDisplayedFormula = value;
    }

    private void updateFormula() {
        final String first = Formatter.doubleToString(mBaseValue);
        final String second = Formatter.doubleToString(mSecondValue);
        final String sign = getSign(mLastOperation);

        if (sign.equals("√")) {
            setFormula(sign + first);
        } else if (!sign.isEmpty()) {
            setFormula(first + sign + second);
        }
    }

    public void setLastKey(String mLastKey) {
        this.mLastKey = mLastKey;
    }

    public void addDigit(int number) {
        final String currentValue = getDisplayedNumber();
        final String newValue = formatString(currentValue + number);
        setValue(newValue);
    }

    private String formatString(String str) {
        // if the number contains a decimal, do not try removing the leading zero anymore, nor add group separator
        // it would prevent writing values like 1.02
        if (str.contains(".")) return str;

        final double doubleValue = Formatter.stringToDouble(str);
        return Formatter.doubleToString(doubleValue);
    }

    private void updateResult(double value) {
        setValue(Formatter.doubleToString(value));
        mBaseValue = value;
    }

    public String getDisplayedNumber() {
        return mDisplayedValue;
    }

    public double getDisplayedNumberAsDouble() {
        return Formatter.stringToDouble(getDisplayedNumber());
    }

    public String getDisplayedFormula() {
        return mDisplayedFormula;
    }

    public void handleResult() {
        mSecondValue = getDisplayedNumberAsDouble();
        calculateResult();
        mBaseValue = getDisplayedNumberAsDouble();
    }

    public void calculateResult() {
        if (!mIsFirstOperation) updateFormula();

        switch (mLastOperation) {
        case Constants.PLUS:
            updateResult(mBaseValue + mSecondValue);
            break;
        case Constants.MINUS:
            updateResult(mBaseValue - mSecondValue);
            break;
        case Constants.MULTIPLY:
            updateResult(mBaseValue * mSecondValue);
            break;
        case Constants.DIVIDE:
            divideNumbers();
            break;
        case Constants.MODULO:
            moduloNumbers();
            break;
        case Constants.POWER:
            powerNumbers();
            break;
        case Constants.ROOT:
            updateResult(Math.sqrt(mBaseValue));
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        mIsFirstOperation = false;
    }

    private void divideNumbers() {
        double resultValue = 0;
        if (mSecondValue != 0) resultValue = mBaseValue / mSecondValue;

        updateResult(resultValue);
    }

    private void moduloNumbers() {
        double resultValue = 0;
        if (mSecondValue != 0) resultValue = mBaseValue % mSecondValue;

        updateResult(resultValue);
    }

    private void powerNumbers() {
        double resultValue = Math.pow(mBaseValue, mSecondValue);
        if (Double.isInfinite(resultValue) || Double.isNaN(resultValue)) resultValue = 0;
        updateResult(resultValue);
    }

    public void handleOperation(String operation) {
        if (mLastKey.equals(Constants.DIGIT)) handleResult();

        mResetValue = true;
        mLastKey = operation;
        mLastOperation = operation;

        if (operation.equals(Constants.ROOT)) calculateResult();
    }

    public void handleClear() {
        final String oldValue = getDisplayedNumber();
        String newValue = "0";
        final int len = oldValue.length();
        int minLen = 1;
        if (oldValue.contains("-")) minLen++;

        if (len > minLen) newValue = oldValue.substring(0, len - 1);

        newValue = newValue.replaceAll("\\.$", "");
        newValue = formatString(newValue);
        setValue(newValue);
        mBaseValue = Formatter.stringToDouble(newValue);
    }

    public void handleReset() {
        resetValues();
        setValue("0");
        setFormula("");
    }

    public void handleEquals() {
        if (mLastKey.equals(Constants.EQUALS)) calculateResult();

        if (!mLastKey.equals(Constants.DIGIT)) return;

        mSecondValue = getDisplayedNumberAsDouble();
        calculateResult();
        mLastKey = Constants.EQUALS;
    }

    public void decimalClicked() {
        String value = getDisplayedNumber();
        if (!value.contains(".")) value += ".";
        setValue(value);
    }

    public void zeroClicked() {
        String value = getDisplayedNumber();
        if (!value.equals("0")) addDigit(0);
    }

    private String getSign(String lastOperation) {
        switch (lastOperation) {
        case Constants.PLUS:
            return "+";
        case Constants.MINUS:
            return "-";
        case Constants.MULTIPLY:
            return "*";
        case Constants.DIVIDE:
            return "/";
        case Constants.MODULO:
            return "%";
        case Constants.POWER:
            return "^";
        case Constants.ROOT:
            return "√";
        }
        return "";
    }

    public void numpadClicked(int id) {
        if (mLastKey.equals(Constants.EQUALS)) mLastOperation = Constants.EQUALS;
        mLastKey = Constants.DIGIT;
        resetValueIfNeeded();

        switch (id) {
        case R.id.btn_decimal:
            decimalClicked();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_0:
            zeroClicked();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_1:
            addDigit(1);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_2:
            addDigit(2);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_3:
            addDigit(3);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_4:
            addDigit(4);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_5:
            addDigit(5);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_6:
            addDigit(6);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_7:
            addDigit(7);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_8:
            addDigit(8);
            break;
        case R.id.btn_9:
            addDigit(9);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/calculator_holder"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.stins.calculator.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/formula"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2.1"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:gravity="right|bottom"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:textSize="@dimen/formula_text_size"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.8"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_margin"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="@dimen/display_text_size"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_modulo"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="mod"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="@dimen/mod_text_size"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_power"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="^"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_root"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="√"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_clear"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="C"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_reset"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="AC"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_7"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="7"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_8"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="8"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_9"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="9"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_divide"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="÷"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_4"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="4"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_5"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="5"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_6"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="6"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_multiply"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="*"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_2"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="2"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_3"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_minus"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="-"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_0"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="0"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_decimal"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="."/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_equals"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="="/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_plus"
        style="@style/MyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="+"/>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

logcat

```
02-11 14:27:36.485 5006-5006/com.example.stins.calculator E/AndroidRuntime:    
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.stins.calculator, PID: 5006
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.stins.calculator/com.example.stins.calculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.widget.TextView.getContext()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.widget.TextView.getContext()' on a null object reference
    at me.grantland.widget.AutofitHelper.<init>(AutofitHelper.java:246)
    at me.grantland.widget.AutofitHelper.create(AutofitHelper.java:62)
    at me.grantland.widget.AutofitHelper.create(AutofitHelper.java:46)
    at com.example.stins.calculator.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

If at all possible, would anyone know how to help ?

I included my logcat as well

Comment: Build > Clean Project

Comment: tried removing that `import com.example.stins.calculator` but it didn't help. I cleaned and rebuilt after that.

Comment: okay give me just a moment

Comment: actually Josh, I don't actually have the java class. It is a widget that is listed as `compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'`

Comment: Would you like me to edit the original post with the CalcImpl java class? If that helps.

Comment: I just updated the post with `CalcImpl.java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to make sure that you have the `annotationProcessor` for `butterknife` setup in your `build.gradle`. You should have a line under `dependencies` that looks like this:

`annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'`.

After you add that run build->rebuild project.

Comment: That was exactly it! Thanks so much! But now the buttons aren't clickable anymore. I'm not sure if I undid something in the process of fixing that.

Comment: that's probably in `@style/MyButton` you're missing active or pressed state styles

Comment: Okay I was actually mistaken, the `android:state_pressed="true"` is already there, the buttons being clicked are not setting the text to the  TextView though.

Comment: in your main activity the methods `setValue` and `setFormula` are not doing anything and I also I don't see any code that's supposed to react to button clicks

Comment: Sorry about that. just relaized I didn't paste the entirety of the MainActivity.java class into the code snippet. I just edited it now.

Comment: Is it just that the buttons have not been assigned an onClick() method to execute? Because it will just either crash or not do anything on press when running in the AVD

Comment: click handler looks ok, try putting a `Toast` in the handler and see if it works at all. (`Toast.makeText(this, "click handler called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`)

Comment: I added the Toast to the numpadClicked(View v) method but it didn't do anything and instead just crashed. The numbers on the numberpad have onClick set to that method as well.

Comment: Correction: The click handler toast works for all numpad buttons. So they do work.

Comment: you are not updating the `mDisplayedValue` variable every time a number is clicked (in `addNumber`) so the next time its `getDisplayedNumber` is called its going to be "0" again. (I'm not sure thats the issue but its definitely an issue as well)

Comment: Okay I see what you are saying. How would I go about having that mDisplayedValue variable updating everytime the number is clicked?

Comment: no clue, looking through the code, it looks like it should work to me

Comment: yeah it seems like the issue lies somewhere with some missing code maybe. Thank you so much though! You've been a huge help!